# Hide the text on a button in android?

Tags: java, android

Please tell me how to hide the text on a button in android.

When I try this code, the button is hidden but I just want to hide the text on the button.

```
Button b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.follow);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Please tell me how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: may be text not gona hide, you have to settext of the button to "".

Comment: dont give any text for button. delete this from xml file android:text="xyz"..

Comment: dont write gone property it will definatly remove ur button

Comment: Try this, b.setText("");

Comment: first you need to get that text from button and hide that text...

Comment: but I want to show button and I want textvalue also but want hide that text..

Comment: Not clear. what do you mean by hide text? I think @userIsAMonkey is right

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have a suggestion if you want to setText to a button but don't want to show it.

Just set the text in the xml

```
android:text="TEXT"
```

then make font to 0

```
android:textSize="0sp"
```

text exist but can't be seen.

Comment: This will work, but this is not very convenient, since you will have to take text size 
 somewhere else additionally the original text size when restoring visibility.
There must be some other solution like a flag.

Answer (score 9):

On your button use `mButton.setTextScaleX(0);` so the text will be hidden and to show use `mButton.setTextScaleX(1);`

Comment: This is a very clever solution that doesn't require resetting the actual text value while changing it's visibility dynamically!

Comment: Thank you, it was most helpful because there I shouldn't store text or textSize, it may be used as a flag.
I would add setTextScale method requires to pass the float param, 
mButton.setTextScaleX(0.0f)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to hide the Text and not the Button  `b.setVisibility(View.GONE)` will not work.

It will hide the button itself and also button will not occupy any space in your layout as you are using View.GONE.

Using `b.setText("")` should help you setting just an empty text on Button.

May be you need to call `invalidate()`to refresh the UI.

Comment: I need text on button for validation but I want to hide text on button

Comment: Do you mean to make it invisible text ?

Comment: Match the text colour to the background colour of your button!!

Answer (score 2):

First take backup of existing text on your button then clear button text to hide text. And to show text again reuse backup text :

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.follow);

//Backup button text
String mButtonText = b.getText();

//Now hide text 
b.setText("");

//To show text again
b.setText(mButtonText);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the button text to just be blank instead of trying to hide the button.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewByID(R.id.ButtonID);
button.setText(" ");
```

This will allow you to change the text of the button within your source, so you will be able to change the button text when an event happens or even just set the button text to blank when it is created.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

This will make the text transparent/hidden. It will keep the original size of the button and keep the original text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

          `<Button
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:textColor="#00000000"/>`

general info:

```
#<alpha><red><green><blue>
```

all in hexadecimal 00 to ff

Answer (score 0):

on your xml. remove the `android:txt=" "` on your button.